# HTML text movement

Tags: html, css

I am new to HTML and CSS and I am trying to learn right now. I am trying to create a basic website and do not know how to put the text and move it wherever I want. Here is the HTML and CSS code

My main question Is how do I change where it is on the screen in CSS?

[picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FSKmc.png)

Thanks!

Comment: FYI, its easier for people to help when you put your code into a jsfiddle and paste the link - jsfiddle.com

Comment: @ThomasSkubicki Or have the code directly in the question

Comment: Thanks! Do you any one of you know how to do it?

Comment: And well... I would say go look around for some CSS tutorials online. There are many parameters you can play with in CSS to position your text where you want, e.g. `position`, `margin` and `padding`. Try checking these out.

Comment: Go to jsfiddle.com, then paste the contents of your html file into the HTML sections, and the CSS file into the CSS section. Now, click on the save button in the top left corner of the page, confirm it, and finally, copy and past the address in your URL bar into the question

Comment: @BrendanGainer well, when you're writing/editing your question, there is a `{}` button you can click on to insert a code snippet. Write your code inside the window that appears and click on "Insert into post" (or something like that).

Answer (score 0):

As you are learning i would suggest for you to go and check out this webpage:
https://www.udemy.com. They offer a lot of courses some of them even free where you can learn more about html and css.

Now below you can find a link to an online school for programmers. They have a lot of examples with code and you should also find answer for your question here:
https://www.w3schools.com

Happy studying!